# SAPUI5 How to decode qrcode from qrcode image

Tags: javascript, sapui5

How to scan QRCode data from QRCode image(jpg/png) that is available in local System. From UI5 library im able to find [BarcodeScanner](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ndc.BarcodeScanner). Using below code im able to open Camera from my device and able to scan the barcodes..

```
sap.ndc.BarcodeScanner.scan(
            function(mResult) {
                alert("We got a bar code\n" +
                    "Result: " + mResult.text + "\n" +
                    "Format: " + mResult.format + "\n" +
                    "Cancelled: " + mResult.cancelled);
            },
            function(Error) {
                alert("Scanning failed: " + Error);
            },
        );
```

But how to decode **QRCode image** data? can someone please help me?

Thankyou in advance

Comment: What do you mean with available? upload a gif/jpg into the browser?

Comment: yeah. qrcode image will be either jpg/png which is available in local system.that QR Image i need to get in to SAPUI5 app and i need to scan and get the content from that QR Code image. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Scanning a QR code from the real world via the camera is not an option? Or do users _have to_ attach image files to the UI5 app?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann, yeah you are right. In Users Local system, user will have qr images, from there user can access QR code

Comment: What platforms do you have to support? Is it Android only? Then you might want to take a look at the new [web API `BarcodeDetector`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_barcodedetector) with which you can also decode static images. But as you can see, the standard is currently not fully implemented by other non-Chromium browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this lib for reading qr codes: https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode

In this function the file is read and the decoded result is outputted in a div container

```
function readFile(oFile) {
  var input = oFile.target;
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function() {
    var dataURL = reader.result;
    decodeImageFromBase64(dataURL, function(decodedInformation) {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = decodedInformation;
    })
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

In this fuction the decoding magic is happen

```
function decodeImageFromBase64(data, callback) {
      qrcode.callback = callback;
      qrcode.decode(data)
    }
```